# How to use interface as a Response Listener in android?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-studio

I have this code working with me, I am confused with the control flow.

How is the interface used here as a Response Listener? How is the overridden method responseObject(JSONObject resp, String type) in LoginActivity class triggering?

And after calling AsyncTask where the control goes?

```
 public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements ResponseListener{

       login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

       login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
            {
                 String username = mUsernameField.getText().toString();
                 String password = mPasswordField.getText().toString();
                 String[] param = {username, password};
                 new ServerRequests.LoginUserAsyncTask(LoginActivity.this,this).execute(param);

            }

    @Override
    public void responseObject(JSONObject resp, String type) {
        try{
            if (resp.has("api_key")) {
                String api_key = resp.getString("api_key");
                String user_id = resp.getString("user");
                Log.i("api_key", api_key);
                SharedPreferences settings =     LoginActivity.this.getSharedPreferences(Constants.NADA_SP_KEY, 0);
                final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                editor.putString(Constants.NADA_API_KEY, api_key);
                editor.putString(Constants.NADA_USER_ID, user_id);
                editor.putBoolean(Constants.NADA_IS_LOGGED_IN, true);
                editor.commit();
                Log.i("first Visit", "False");
                String should_show_questions_screen = resp.getString("should_set_basic_questions");
                if (should_show_questions_screen.compareToIgnoreCase("true")==0){

                    Intent intent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,RegistrationSuccessfulScreen.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();


                }else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UserNavigationActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }




//Heres my ServerRequest Class which uses AsyncTask

    public class ServerRequests {

      public static class LoginUserAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        static JSONObject udetails;

        Context mContext;
        ResponseListener mResponseListener;
        SweetAlertDialog progressDialog;

        public LoginUserAsyncTask(Context mContext,ResponseListener listener) {
            this.mContext = mContext;
            this.mResponseListener = listener;

        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog =new SweetAlertDialog(mContext, SweetAlertDialog.PROGRESS_TYPE);
            progressDialog.getProgressHelper().setBarColor(Color.parseColor("#A5DC86"));
            progressDialog.setTitleText("please wait connecting..");
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.show();


        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = null;
            udetails = new JSONObject();
            String response_data = "";
            if (params.length == 2) {
                try {
                    post = new HttpPost(Config.SERVER_BASE_URL + "/login");
                    udetails.put("username", params[0]);
                    udetails.put("password", params[1]);
                    SharedPreferences settings = mContext.getSharedPreferences(Constants.NADA_SP_KEY, 0);
                    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString(Config.USER_NAME, params[0]).commit();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                try {
                    post = new HttpPost(Config.SERVER_BASE_URL + "/login_with_fb");
                    udetails.put("fb_id", params[0]);
                    udetails.put("fb_auth_token", params[1]);
                    SharedPreferences settings = mContext.getSharedPreferences(Constants.NADA_SP_KEY, 0);
                    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString(Config.USER_NAME, params[0]).commit();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            try {
                StringEntity se = new StringEntity(udetails.toString());
                se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
                post.setEntity(se);
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                int response_code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                response_data = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                Log.i("api_token", response_data);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            return response_data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {

            progressDialog.dismiss();
            JSONObject resp = new JSONObject();
            try {
                resp = new JSONObject(response);
                if (resp.has("status")) {
                    if (resp.getString("status").compareToIgnoreCase("unauthorised")==0){

                        AppMsg appMsg = AppMsg.makeText((Activity)mContext, resp.getString("message"), style);
                        appMsg.show();

                    }
                }
                mResponseListener.responseObject(resp,"LOGIN");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                AppMsg appMsg = AppMsg.makeText((Activity)mContext, "Something went wrong", style);
                appMsg.show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
}


//Here's Interface Which has this method


    public interface ResponseListener {
        public void responseObject(JSONObject data,String type);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `LoginActivity` implements `ResponseListener`. In this line: `new ServerRequests.LoginUserAsyncTask(LoginActivity.this,this).execute(param);`, you pass your activity twice into the `LoginUserAsyncTask` constructor. Notice that the constructor takes in a `Context` and a `ResponseListener`. You can do this because your activity implements `ResponseListener`.

Now `LoginUserAsyncTask` can call the `responseObject` method on your activty because it has a refrence to it as a `ResponseListener`. It does that in the `onPostExecute` method of the `AsyncTask`. The activity is kind of listning to when the task is done, then it's `responseObject` method is called.

Becaus the work of the  `AsyncTask` is done asynchronously it returns "straight away" and the next statement is executed.

I also think your missing part of the first method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer this helped me to understand it better... :-)